# How to find the minimum floating-point value accepted by betareg package?

Tags: r, floating-point, precision, betareg

I'm doing a [beta regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf) in R, which requires values between 0 and 1, endpoints excluded, i.e. (0,1) instead of [0,1].

I have some 0 and 1 values in my dataset, so I'd like to convert them to the smallest possible neighbor, such as 0.0000...0001 and 0.9999...9999. I've used `.Machine$double.xmin` (which gives me 2.225074e-308), but `betareg()` still gives an error:

> invalid dependent variable, all observations must be in (0, 1)

If I use 0.000001 and 0.999999, I got a different set of errors:

> 1: In betareg.fit(X, Y, Z, weights, offset, link, link.phi, type, control) :
>         failed to invert the information matrix: iteration stopped prematurely
>       2: In sqrt(wpp) :
>        Error in chol.default(K) : 
>         the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite

Only if I use 0.0001 and 0.9999 I can run without errors. Is there any way I can improve this minimum values with betareg? Or should I just be happy with that?

Comment: Try it with `eps` (displacement from 0 and 1) first equal to 1e-4 (as you have here) and thenwith 1e-3. If the results of the models differ in any way you care about, that's great. If they are, you need to be **very** careful, because it suggests your answers will be very sensitive to assumptions.

Comment: Ben:  I think you meant "If the results of the models *do not* differ".

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `eps` (displacement from 0 and 1) first equal to 1e-4 (as you have here) and then with 1e-3. If the results of the models don't differ in any way you care about, that's great. If they are, you need to be **very** careful, because it suggests your answers will be very sensitive to assumptions.

In the example below the dispersion parameter phi changes a lot, but the intercept and slope parameter don't change very much.

If you do find that the parameters change by a worrying amount for your particular data, then you need to think harder about the process by which zeros and ones arise, and model that process appropriately, e.g.

- a *censored-data* model: zero/one arise through a minimum/maximum detection threshold, models the zero/one values as actually being somewhere in the tails or
- a *hurdle*/*zero-one inflation* model: zeros and ones arise through a separate process from the rest of the data, use a binomial or multinomial model to characterize zero vs. (0,1) vs. one, then use a Beta regression on the (0,1) component)

Questions about these steps are probably more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) than for SO.

### sample data

```
set.seed(101)
library(betareg)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(500))
rbeta2 <- function(n, prob=0.5, d=1) {
    rbeta(n, shape1=prob*d, shape2=(1-prob)*d)
}
dd$y <- rbeta2(500,plogis(1+5*dd$x),d=1)
dd$y[dd$y<1e-8] <- 0
```

### trial fitting function

```
ss <- function(eps) {
    dd <- transform(dd,
                    y=pmin(1-eps,pmax(eps,y)))
    m <- try(betareg(y~x,data=dd))
    if (inherits(m,"try-error")) return(rep(NA,3))
    return(coef(m))
}
ss(0)  ## fails
ss(1e-8) ## fails
ss(1e-4)
## (Intercept)           x       (phi) 
##   0.3140810   1.5724049   0.7604656
ss(1e-3)  ## also fails
ss(1e-2)
## (Intercept)           x       (phi) 
##   0.2847142   1.4383922   1.3970437
ss(5e-3)
## (Intercept)           x       (phi) 
##   0.2870852   1.4546247   1.2029984
```

### try it for a range of values

```
evec <- seq(-4,-1,length=51)
res <- t(sapply(evec, function(e) ss(10^e)) )
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(e=10^evec,reshape2::melt(res)),
       aes(e,value,colour=Var2))+
    geom_line()+scale_x_log10()
```

[image]